# Making list items appear around the circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/220px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png">
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Is there anyway to have list items appear around the circle. This is what i've got so far https://jsfiddle.net/7bLzf97g/10/. I want 1 to 6 to appear around the circle instead of listing vertically. I would really appreciate your help guys. Thanks

Comment: Are you only interested in 6 li or it could be a different amount of elements around the circle?

Comment: It's just an example could be any

Comment: Ok, and what about the circle? It could be a different polygon? You are using an image, why don't using a div with rounded squares?

Comment: It would be better if it is an image as I want to use it for other purposes aswell.

Comment: Should the items follow the radius of the circle or simple ltr?

Comment: ideally follow the radius of the circle but its not a biggie